# postfix ssl cert permission issues

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

I am setting up a Postfix server on CentOS 7.  Selinux would be the obvious culprit, so it is disabled. and I am having the same issue.

My certs are stored in `/etc/ssl/certs/<domain>`. My `master.cf` is pointing to the correct location of the file from the logs. But I'm still getting the error below:

```
warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file "/etc/ssl/certs/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem": disabling TLS support

Sep 5 15:53:07 mail postfix/smtpd[1440]: warning: TLS library problem: 1440:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:402:fopen('"/etc/ssl/certs/mail.example.com/fullchain.pem"','r')
```

When I do an `ls` on that directory I get:

```
[root@mail mail.example.com]# ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   46 Sep  5 13:54 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root  150 Sep  5 13:54 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1769 Sep  5 13:54 fullchain.pem
-rw-------. 1 root root 3272 Sep  5 13:54 privkey.pem

[root@mail mail.example.com]# pwd
/etc/ssl/certs/mail.example.com
```

Comment: Possible dup - https://serverfault.com/questions/433003/postfix-warning-cannot-get-rsa-private-key-from-file/433062.

Comment: Instead of simply disabling a security feature (SELinux), you should read it's documentation and configure it properly.